# Populating select options from db - laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel Collective and Laravel 5.2... I'm kinda new at this, so please if someone can help, I would be grateful. 
I want to populate data to my view, 
this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\SaveProfileRequest;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Clas;
use App\Profile;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class ClassesController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex() {
        return view('admin.classes.list', [
            'classes' => Clas::get()
        ]);
    }



    public function postIndex(Request $request) {
        $class = Clas::create([
            'profile_id'=> 
            'name' => $request ->input('class-name'),
        ]);

        if($class->id) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
                'type'=> 'success',
                'message' => 'Успешно записан нов клас!'

            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
            'type'=> 'danger',
            'message' => 'Класът не е записан!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in my View I have this

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('class-name','Клас:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::text('class-name', null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'например: 8а' ]) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('profile-name','Избери профил:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::select('profile-name') !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div align="center">
        {!! Form::submit('Запиши', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

My question is how to pass the data? What should i write in the controller and in the view to connect them?

Comment: Are you returning a view after making a request to `postIndex` ?

Comment: Yes I do, but now it doesn't work because `'profile_id'=>` is empty.

Comment: update your answer with complete controller or postIndex(Request $request) . what to see the full code

Comment: There it is, I updated.

Comment: your `getIndex()` is return a view, not your `postIndex()` and you don't have profile_id field in your form, are you passing it through URL ?

Comment: It return this `if($class->id) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
                'type'=> 'success',
                'message' => 'Успешно записан нов клас!'

            ]);
        }`

or this

 `return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
            'type'=> 'danger',
            'message' => 'Класът не е записан!'
        ]);`

Comment: It's the same page with a message. And it works in the other pages of my project, just here I dont know what to do with 'profile_id' cuz the 'Clas' table is connected with it.

Comment: When I press 'Submit' i get this: 

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`school_system`.`classes`, CONSTRAINT `classes_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `classes` (`profile_id`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (["\u0418\u0422, \u041c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430","\u0418\u0422, \u041c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430, \u0410\u0415","ITAAA"], , 2016-02-17 14:44:15, 2016-02-17 14:44:15))**

Comment: what does this `Clas::get()` returns , does it contain the `profile_id`? do you want to add the profile_id field to a hidden field in your form? Or is this a profile_id of an authenticated user?

Comment: Yes, `Clas::get()` contains both `name` and `profile_id`. `profile_id` connect me to table Profile with names of the profiles i just want to visualize the names in my drop down list in the view.

Comment: Please show me the format of what Clas::get() returns, You can do `dd(Clas::get())` and copy the output so i will know how to use them . I don't know if its returning array or object

Comment: `class Clas extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
             'profile_id',
             'name'
    ];`

Comment: I will modify your view

Comment: the Clas table: 

`Schema::create('classes', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('profile_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('profile_id')
                ->references('id')->on('profiles');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to you comment.

This returns a list (array) to the view:

EDITED

```
public function getIndex() {
    return view('admin.classes.list', [
       //'classes' => Clas::get() //returns object, profile
       'profiles' => Profile::lists('name', 'id');  //returns array
    ]);
}
```

To populate the select menu with lists of profile_id and name
NB: I changed `profile-name` to `profile_id`

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('profile_id','Избери профил:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::select('profile_id', $profiles) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your postIndex:

```
public function postIndex(Request $request) {
    $class = Clas::create([
        'profile_id'=> $request->get('profile_id'),
        'name' => $request ->input('class-name'),
    ]);

    if($class->id) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
            'type'=> 'success',
            'message' => 'Успешно записан нов клас!'

        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
        'type'=> 'danger',
        'message' => 'Класът не е записан!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: But still doesn't show the list of the profiles in the drop down

Comment: inside `getIndex()` do this `dd(Clas::lists('name', 'profile_id'));` then refresh your index page and show me the output

Comment: `Collection {#201 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your table? also do `dd(Clas::get())` and show me

Comment: yes i have data, `dd(Clas::get())` and i have this : `Collection {#202 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: okay thats it. means you don't have any data in your table, your `classes` table is empty

Comment: yes, the data I need to get is in the Profile table I need to get it from there

Comment: I'm making an admin panel from wich the user must put data in the tables

Comment: in that case you should be using App`Profile

Comment: So in here the user must type the name of a class and select a profile ( which is already created ) from a drop down and after that save

Comment: I'm using `App\Profile` and `App\Clas`

Comment: I  have edited the answer. `'profiles' => Profile::lists('name', 'id'); ` this will populate the `select` field with available `profiles`

Comment: I made it, just changed `Clas` to `Profile`

Comment: Yes, thank you very very much! And last question ... How can I format the
`{!! Form::select('profile-id', $profiles) !!}` like adding a class , im using bootstrap

Comment: Right now when I try to save my data I have this mssg: 

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'profile_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `classes` (`profile_id`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 8a, 2016-02-17 16:55:43, 2016-02-17 16:55:43))**

Comment: **8a** Is an iput I made, but it looks like it doesn't save anything in `profile_id`

Comment: 8a? I don't understand

Comment: "8a" is an input I made `'name' => $request ->input('class-name'),` the `class-name` is "8a"

Comment: In that case and I pick a profile from the drop down and when I submit it gives me this mssg i share up there

Comment: Change class-name to class_name

Comment: But thats okay the problem is with the profiles, it doesnt get any data.

Comment: Oh i fix it, it was a mistake with the name.

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have isdues

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#basic-usage

You can pass view variables by calling the function `view( string $script, array $viewVariables )`